# Java - Token flow OAuth 2 E2E with code

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt, cloud-foundry

I'm New to security & JAVA and I need to implement token follow of OAuth2, this is the exact flow which I need to implement (if there is some library which can help it's great )

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/oauth2/authorization-code-request-response.html

How can I achieve it with JAVA, I want to use some library that provide this functionality. the token flow should be against the UAA but any other similar example will be very helpful.
i've found this example but not sure how to use/test it E2E with UAA
Postman will be very helpful to simulate it...

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/oauth2

UAA context

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you Spring as the most popular framework for building web apps in Java. It has Spring Security module that can facilitate developing OAuth 2.0 clients as well as resource servers, as shown [here](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2/blob/master/simple/src/main/resources/application.yml) or [here](https://github.com/making/oauth2-sso-demo/blob/master/resource/src/main/resources/application.properties).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what I need is step by step code solution, and how to test it ? this is the reason that I put bounty :)

Comment: There are 4 different flows in OAuth 2.0. Which exactly flow do you need? UAA comes with sample apps which support Authorization Code Flow - do you need guide how to set it up, or?

Comment: I need to support this flow http://tutorials.jenkov.com/oauth2/authorization-code-request-response.html , with uaa ....thanks

Comment: So how should I write the code to implement it, can you please provide example with the links you have provided ?

Answer (score 1):

For a detailed explanation of the OAuth 2.0 flow, visit [RFC 6749 Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).  Regarding a step by step solution, you ought to see some tutorials such as [this article explaining how to create a Spring REST API using OAuth 2.0](http://websystique.com/spring-security/secure-spring-rest-api-using-oauth2/).  This article goes through code as well as creating Postman requests. With regards to mocking/tests, I've previously created a test suite for the OAuth 2.0 using TestNG and Mockito.

The more you develop and research, the more you shall find ways of improving or rather change the way you design your code.  That said if you really want to abide by the OAuth 2.0 flow, you should properly understand the flow (which can be relatively vague at times) in the RFC 6749 link.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Google API clinet library sample. Try this if it helps

```
    public class ServletSample extends AbstractAuthorizationCodeServlet {

  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws IOException {
    // do stuff
  }

  @Override
  protected String getRedirectUri(HttpServletRequest req) throws ServletException, IOException {
    GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl(req.getRequestURL().toString());
    url.setRawPath("/oauth2callback");
    return url.build();
  }

  @Override
  protected AuthorizationCodeFlow initializeFlow() throws IOException {
    return new AuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(BearerToken.authorizationHeaderAccessMethod(),
        new NetHttpTransport(),
        new JacksonFactory(),
        new GenericUrl("https://server.example.com/token"),
        new BasicAuthentication("s6BhdRkqt3", "7Fjfp0ZBr1KtDRbnfVdmIw"),
        "s6BhdRkqt3",
        "https://server.example.com/authorize").setCredentialDataStore(
            StoredCredential.getDefaultDataStore(
                new FileDataStoreFactory(new File("datastoredir"))))
        .build();
  }

  @Override
  protected String getUserId(HttpServletRequest req) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // return user ID
  }
}

public class ServletCallbackSample extends AbstractAuthorizationCodeCallbackServlet {

  @Override
  protected void onSuccess(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, Credential credential)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.sendRedirect("/");
  }

  @Override
  protected void onError(
      HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, AuthorizationCodeResponseUrl errorResponse)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    // handle error
  }

  @Override
  protected String getRedirectUri(HttpServletRequest req) throws ServletException, IOException {
    GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl(req.getRequestURL().toString());
    url.setRawPath("/oauth2callback");
    return url.build();
  }

  @Override
  protected AuthorizationCodeFlow initializeFlow() throws IOException {
    return new AuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(BearerToken.authorizationHeaderAccessMethod(),
        new NetHttpTransport(),
        new JacksonFactory(),
        new GenericUrl("https://server.example.com/token"),
        new BasicAuthentication("s6BhdRkqt3", "7Fjfp0ZBr1KtDRbnfVdmIw"),
        "s6BhdRkqt3",
        "https://server.example.com/authorize").setCredentialDataStore(
            StoredCredential.getDefaultDataStore(
                new FileDataStoreFactory(new File("datastoredir"))))
        .build();
  }

  @Override
  protected String getUserId(HttpServletRequest req) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // return user ID
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/samples/oauth2 contains sample code for performing oauth2 using Spring Security.